# Javascript console.log() returns a reference error to a php string

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am trying to output the array values into the console but I get an undefined error:

**ERROR**

```
ReferenceError: Ciencia is not defined
```

**CODE**

```
 $sql = "SELECT topic FROM book_list WHERE topic != '' ORDER BY topic ASC";
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        <?php 
            while($topic = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){?>
                console.log(<?php echo $topic['topic']; ?>);
        <?php }?>
```

If I output the sql in the mysql console I get this

```
+-------------+
| topic       |
+-------------+
| Ciencia     |
| Comedia     |
| Comedia     |
| Matematicas |
| Science     |
+-------------+
```

Thanks!

Comment: Read the generated source and you'll see your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like it's trying `console.log(Ciencia)` instead of `console.log("Ciencia")`.

Change your line to:

```
console.log("<?php echo $topic['topic']; ?>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the PHP string to a Javascript string, rather than trying to use the PHP string itself as an expression. `json_encode()` is good for this.

```
console.log(<?php echo json_encode($topic['topic']); ?>);
```

This is better than just putting quotes around the echo statement, in case the PHP variable contains special characters that need to be encoded (e.g. quotes).